# What's the difference between llround() and round() function in C++?

Tags: c++, rounding, built-in

so the reason why I have this question is that I was doing a problem in which we had to round the final answer. Now,

```
cout << round(answer); //this didn't pass one test case
```

```
//the following block of code passed all test cases
if (answer-(int)answer>0.5) cout << int(answer)+1; 
else cout << (int)answer;
```

```
cout << llround(answer); //this passed all test cases
```

So, what is the difference between `round()` and `llround()` for this type of behavior? If the `answer` variable would have been so big to not fit in the `int` type, then `if-else` block of code shouldn't have worked either. So what am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: `round` returns floating point value, while `lround` returns `long` and `llround` returns `long long`

Comment: Your if-else is actually incorrect. Both `round` and `llround` round the halfway case away from zero. Change `>` to `>=`.

Comment: please dont fix issues in your question that are related to your question. You ask why there is a difference and `>` instead of `>=` is one reason for a difference. Don't fix that in the question. I rolled back the edit

Comment: @idclev463035818 May I know the reason why people downvote questions on SO? this is a genuine question I had and SO was my last resort. I asked my peers but they didn't have an answer to this question. Moreover, I tried to look at other posts as well.

Comment: @jukebox I cannot tell you why others vote, how could I? I did consider to vote, because there is a difference between `llround` and `round` that you could have looked up in some reference (eg [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round)), but your question contains no evidence that you did any reasearch before asking, sometimes that alone can be reason enough for a downvote. You say it is your "last resort" and I want to believe you, but you should have included anything you already found out in the question, anything helps others to help you.

Comment: the official words: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down. Btw a single vote is nothing. If your question is "ok" a single downvote (or even more) will prevent nobody from writing an answer

Comment: not including a [mcve], actual and expected output as it should be is another reason why this question is difficult to answer properly

Answer (score 1):

`round()` returns a floating point value, while your alternatives return integer value. With the default formatting of `cout`, there should be no difference in the output, but if you have changed the formatting, there might be a difference:

```
double answer = 1.5;
cout << round(answer) << " " << llround(answer) << "\n"; // Prints 2 2
cout << std::fixed << setprecision(5);
cout << round(answer) << " " << llround(answer) << "\n"; // Prints 2.00000 2
```